# Utilizing Banno API through Visual Studio Code REST Client Extension

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

Has anyone been successful in testing either Banno API within the REST Client extension of Visual Studio Code? I know the Postman library is out there but was looking at other avenues of testing as we get into utilizing the API.

The issue I am running into is with the Authorization header. I have the Private Key saved as a Shared variable within the extension, however no matter what I try it does not recognize it as a valid header.

Comment: Can you please update your question with some additional detail such as a snippet of how you're trying to set up an API call? I'm not sure what you mean by a "Private Key" in this circumstance as none of our endpoints take a Private Key or Public Key in any _direct_ manner.

Comment: As an example, I have a few different variables where I set the base URL for the Consumer API and use a different variable for the Access Token a la `GET {{BANNO_API_ENVIRONMENT}}/a/consumer/api/v0/users/{{USER_ID}}/accounts
Authorization: Bearer {{ACCESS_TOKEN}}`

Comment: Another example with the Admin API in mind where I have a variable for the base URL and a different variable for the Access Token (with a name to differentiate from an Access Token from the Consumer API) a la `GET {{PLATFORM_BASE}}/a/password-reset/api/v0/institutions/{{INSTITUTION_ID}}/settings
Authorization: Bearer {{PLATFORM_TOKEN}}`

Comment: It doesn't render well in the comments, but there is a newline between after the endpoint so `Authorization: Bearer {{ACCESS_TOKEN}}` and  `Authorization: Bearer {{PLATFORM_TOKEN}}` are on the very next line for their respective usages.